# Xamarin c#: Lock inside the same lock

Tags: xamarin, concurrency, locking

I am having problem with locks, if I have code A and B where A has a lock calling code B who also have the same lock. Will this operation cause a problem in the future.

```
method CodeA () {
    lock(A) {
       CodeB ();
    }
}

method CodeB () {
  lock(A) {
    some database code.
  }
}
```

Reason I ask was I currently facing some crash in the application and seeing there is a lock like above. The crash usually happen very soon when I tapping the list view. After I removed the lock in CodeA above, the crash not seem to happen, I mean not yet..... I will try an hour or two continuously if things ok, I assume it was an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem, since .NET `Monitor`s and therefore also the `lock` statement are recursive.
If they would not be, you would also see a deadlock here, and not a crash.
=> Your crash must have another reason.